# Can same method be used with and without ref?

Tags: c#

I have a method which takes ref parameter.Is there a way  to use the same method( without overload ) by not passing parameter as ref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the same method( without overload ) by not passing parameter as ref?

Yes, but this feature is probably no help to you.

In C# 4 it will be optional to use "ref" on a call to a COM object that takes an optional ref parameter.

The reason for this new feature is because there are many legacy COM objects that were designed for use with VB6. VB6 allows you to omit ref parameters. C# previously did not, which meant that to call these methods from C# you'd have to do this:

```
object missing = Type.Missing;
object abc = 10;
foo.Blah(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref abc, ref missing);
```

Yuck. In C# 4 you can simply say

```
foo.Blah( whatever : 10 );
```

and the compiler fills in all the refs and whatnot for you.

This feature only works on legacy COM objects, and only in C# 4. In other scenarios, you still have to pass things as "ref" if that's what the signature requires.

Comment: Dear Eric ,ca u share some link which has more information no this?
And here foo.Blah( whatever : 10 ); what is whatever? is it a type u need to specify or a key word pls explain?

Comment: @Ravisha: in C# 4 you can call a method that takes optional parameters by specifying just the parameters you want to pass by their names.  So if you have M(int x= 1, int y = 2, int z = 0) then you can say M( y : 123 ) and we will call M(1, 123, 0).

Answer (score 10):

No.  The ref keyword specifies that the method may modify the value passed (the reference if a non-value type, I believe).

The compiler will enforce the 'ref-ness' of the parameter to ensure that, as the consumer, you're aware that the value may differ after the call.

If you really want to not have your variable change, make a copy and call it with the copy.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, if the method signature specifies ref, then you need to pass the parameter as ref.  That way the compiler knows that the value needs to be initialized before passing, as opposed to passing something as out, where it gets initialized / assigned inside of the method.

Answer (score 1):

No... you could presumably make a copy of the value you want to pass in as a parameter so that the ref wouldn't modify your original value?